# java linux centos DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: java, linux, installation

I have download java_ee_sdk-6u2-unix-ml.sh for install on CENTOS.

But when try install - receive this error:

```
This program requires DISPLAY environment variable to be set.
Please re-run after assigning an appropriate value to DISPLAY.
```

But this is server - I cannot install graphic system.
What can i do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit bash profile

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

set variable

```
export DISPLAY=<VALUE>
```

save and close and to test

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

Comment: What value does display usually contain? Can you provide an example of what you have on your system?

Comment: Just assigning some value to $DISPLAY is not helpful -- the J2EE installer tries to connect to an X server, and if there is none, it will not work. The error message usually is "Entering setup...                               
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable."

Answer (score 9):

Try this, before executing:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

If you're connecting through Putty to a headless system, don't forget to have X11 client on your local machine.

Comment: Works in Mac OS 10.9.2

Answer (score 4):

You can either:

1. Generate an answer file on any machine wich has GUI (run setup in *dry run* mode)

   `./java_ee_sdk-6u2-unix-ml.sh -n template`

   and then use that template on server machine with *silent mode* option

   `./java_ee_sdk-6u2-unix-ml.sh -a template -s`
2. Unzip installation manually